# Copy two linked lists recursively by mixing items

Tags: c, linked-list

I need to copy two linked lists recursively and return a new `list`. The way I need to copy them is one element from list1, one from the list2. If one list is shorter than the other just append the remaining elements of the longer list.

Example input: `list1 = [1,2,3], list2 = [4,5,6,7]; result = [1,4,2,5,3,6,7];`

Here's my defective (now correct) code:

```
node *copy(node *list1, node *list2)
{
    if (list1 == NULL && list2 == NULL) return NULL;

    else if (list1 != NULL && list2 != NULL) {
      node *result;
      result = newnode();

      result->data = list1->data;
      result->next = newnode();
      result->next->data = list2->data;

      result->next->next = copy(list1->next, list2->next);

      return result;
    }
    else if (list1 != NULL && list2 == NULL) {
      node *result; 
      result = newnode();

      result->data = list1->data;
      result->next = copy(list1->next, NULL);

              return result;
    }
    else if (list1 == NULL && list2 != NULL) {
      node *result;
      result = newnode();

      result->data = list2->data;
      result->next = copy(NULL, list2->next);

              return result;
    }           
}
```

Can someone point the mistakes I'm making ?

Edit: Now it works. I was missing two return statements.

Comment: It has to be recursive? can't be a simple bucle, like a for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing return statements in the bottom two else if branches.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the number of blocks by putting it all in one loop:

```
node *copy_two_interlaced(node *list1, node *list2)
{
    node *result=NULL, **pp = &result;

    while (list1 || list2) {
      if (list1) {
        *pp = newnode();

        (*pp)->data = list1->data;
        (*pp)->next = NULL;
        list1 = list1->next;
        pp = &(*pp)->next;
        }
      if (list2) {
        *pp = newnode();

        (*pp)->data = list2->data;
        (*pp)->next = NULL;
        list2 = list2->next;
        pp = &(*pp)->next;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Oh, sorry, this is not recursive. Here is a (very ugly) recursive version:

```
node *copy_two_interlaced_recursive(node *list1, node *list2)
{
    node *result=NULL;

      if (list1) {
        result = newnode();
        result->data = list1->data;
        result->next = copy_two_interlaced(list2, list1->next);
        return result;
        }
      if (list2) {
        result = copy_two_interlaced(list2, NULL);
        }
    } 
    return result;
}
```